# С# Как считать string из hex

Tags: c#

У меня есть файл в котором есть начало считывания строкового значения C1 00 00 00 (193 офсет) и кол-во строк 0F 00 00 00 (15), строки разделяются 0x00 + 8 левых байт
Как мне занести в array эти строки?
Вот как код выглядит в 010 Editor С++

```
    struct Names{
    string Char;
    FSkip(8);
} ;

   struct Name{
        for( i = 1; i <= fileSummary.NameCount; i++ ){
        Names ssssssssssss <open=true>;
        }
    } name <open=true>;
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что у вас есть бинарный файл, в котором сначала записаны 2 числа (смещение и количество строк) а затем идут строки? Первое смещение имеет какое-то осмысленное значение применительно к строкам, которые необходимо прочитать?

Comment: А это точно C#? Не узнаю синтаксис.

Comment: @rdorn Совершенно верно!

Comment: @Андрей NOP это C++ - пример того как это работает в 010 Editor

Comment: Исправьте тогда метки и заголовок, зачем вводить в заблуждение...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если файл не слишком большой, удобнее всего вычитать его целиком в память (например, используя метод `File.ReadAllBytes`) и просканировать обычным циклом. Этот ответ и пример полностью полагается на предположение что файл не слишком большой.

В цикле необходимо будет конвертировать массивы байт в .NET типы. Для получения числа из массива байт удобно использовать класс [BitConverter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-an-int). Этот класс предполагает что число записано в [Little Endian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). К счастью, у вас в условии именно такой порядок байт.

Для получения строки из массива байт можно использовать класс [Encoding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). В условии не указано, в какой кодировке хранится текст в файле. Для упрощения я предположил что используется кодировка ASCII (таким образом, я могу воспользоваться преднастроенным экземпляром Encoding доступным через статическое свойство Encoding.ASCII). Тем не менее, пример можно легко переделать под другие кодировки. В большинстве случаев должно быть достаточно выбрать подходящее статическое свойство класса Encoding (Unicode, UTF8, и т.д.).

Для того, чтобы не вводить дополнительные переменные (список строк для хранения результата, список байт для чтения строки), в нижеприведенном примере используется функция, которая выделяет строки напрямую из массива байт с помощью индексов, и использует оператор `yield` чтобы автоматически добавить строку в перечислитель. Т.к. такой подход немного усложняет код (в пользу краткости), я так же добавил комментарии в тех местах, где теоретически может быть непонятно.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Читает из файла N строк закодированных в формате ASCII. Число N задается вторым двойным 
    /// словом в начале файла.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytes">Массив байт</param>
    /// <returns>Возвращает перечислитель строк, который можно использовать в цикле foreach</returns>
    static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(byte[] bytes) {
        // прочитать смещение и число строк записанные в начале файла
        // по заданию, каждое значение занимает 4 байта (dword)
        // в .NET 4 байта занимают Int32 (int) и UInt32(uint)
        // в этом примере выбран Int32 для урощения кода, 
        // т.к. метод ASCII.GetString требует параметры этого типа. 
        Int32 offset = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        Int32 linesCount = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4);
        int start = offset; // используется для запоминания начала строки
        // перечисляем каждый байт пока не получим все строки или не закончится массив
        for (
            int i /*позиция в массиве*/ = offset, 
            n /*счетчик строк*/ = 0; 
            i < bytes.Length && n < linesCount; i++) {

            if (bytes[i] == 0) { // значит достигли конца строки
                // вычисляем смещение начала строки и длину строки
                int index = start;
                int count = i - start;
                // ---
                i += 8; // отступаем 8 байт чтобы попасть в начало следующей строки
                n++;    // увеличиваем счетчик строк
                // запоминаем начало следующей строки.
                // i засинхронизируется со start по завершении цикла командой i++
                start = i + 1; 
                // добываем строку текста и добавляем ее в перечислитель командой yield return
                yield return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, index, count);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вау я просто в шоке от того как вы подробно всё расписали! спасибо большое, то что надо!